# Is there a way to disable the left-right arrows beside a numeric UI property?

Tags: python, interface

I have a portion of my Add-On with limited space.
I would like to display an Integer number but if it's a 3 digit number, it get's cut away by the two arrows left and right.
Is there a way to disable these arrows?

Here 200 is shown as 20
[image: 200 shown as 20]

Because of the +- arrows on the side
[image: Because of the arrows]

The real value is only shown when edited.
[image: Showing real number at editing]

It is defined as a grid and it should stay like that. (The size of the 3 parts should be the same.)
Any way to get around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect answer but I hope it will be helpful.

use `slider = True`

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "TEST"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.prop(context.scene, 'slider', slider=True)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.slider = bpy.props.IntProperty()


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.slider


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately even with a slider, only two digits are displayed. (Also, the field is then colored according the slider value which looks odd.) I was using a grid scale of 2x2 as I wanted to have quite large buttons. After I reduced the scale to X=1 and Y=1.5, the three digits are displayed. But the buttons are of course smaller. It's a workaround but not really a solution.